# Locate process running in all my servers using powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to find or list if a specific process is runing in all servers in my domain using powershell?

For exemple, I would like to list all servers in my domain that is running `"abc.exe"`?

Comment: Hi Vitor. Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53766158/edit) with what you already tried and how it failed (error messages, output, description of behavior that deviated from what you expected)

Answer (score 0):

the CIM/WMI cmdlets can get the process list from remote systems [unless they are blocked]. i've only the one system to test with, but this will work with multiple systems listed in the `ComputerName` parameter.

if you have an older version of PoSh [pre-v-3, i think] you may need to use WMI instead of CIM.

```
$GCIMI_Params = @{
    ClassName = 'CIM_process'
    Filter = "Name = 'Firefox.exe'"
    ComputerName = 'LocalHost'
    }
Get-CimInstance @GCIMI_Params
```

that returned 7 `firefox.exe` processes - roughly the number of tabs i have open at the moment.